# Convert date to format ISO8601 UTC timestamp + ms

Tags: bash, utc, iso8601

I'm using this command to check the last modify date on the file.

```
stat -c '%y' TEST_FILE.tar
```

result in this date format: `2023-08-21 05:16:10.802947000 +0200`

However in may bash script i want to display the date with this format ISO8601 UTC timestamp + ms

```
date --utc +%FT%T.%3NZ
```

Expected time in this format: `2023-08-21T03:16:10.854Z`

how to get this format?

Comment: Please always tag your question with relevant language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formatting capability of `date`:

```
date -d "`stat -c '%y' TEST_FILE.tar`" +%FT%T.%3NZ
```

The option `-d` lets `date` format the given time, not `now`. You need the double quotation marks to include the blanks in the argument.